# If DIV has class toggle a SPAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this issue where I have two pieces of JavasScript that I'd like to combine.

There is a part that does this:

```
$('div.more-content:has(.requiredError)').fadeIn(0);
```

and then a separate item that I'd like to execute if the above condition is true:

```
$('.show-more').find('span').fadeToggle(0);
```

Now I tried combining them in a IF, ELSE statement but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you tried and what results you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('div.more-content:has(.requiredError)')
    .fadeIn(0, function(){
        $('.show-more span')
            .fadeToggle(0);
});
```

Comment: A slight change to your code worked: $('div.more-content:has(.requiredError)')

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a condition, you have a jQuery object which may or may not be empty. You detect that by measuring its length:

```
if ($('div.more-content:has(.requiredError)').fadeIn(0).length) {
    $('.show-more').find('span').fadeToggle(0);
}
```